# Empty left margin on <body> on mobile devices using Bootstrap

Tags: css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap, margins

I'm working on a site using the Bootstrap framework and noticed that on mobile devices there's an empty white margin on the right hand side of the window. I believe this is some sort of issue with the  tag although I can't pinpoint it.

There are 20px margins but if I remove them the .brand logo shifts partially off the screen on the right hand side.

You can view the problem [here](http://theplaybook.co).

Sorry to not provide the code here. I'm just not even sure which CSS to provide as I can't identify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the block which had the heading 'Download original swipe files to ensure your success.' you have the text, an image to the side, and the caption 'one click download of swipe file'

The caption is actually a svg file and I think at some viewports it's too wide for the bootstrap column and it's disrupting the grid. I can't tell for sure, but you could try temporarily removing the caption and see what happens.

The behaviour I'm describing is most obvious when the browser window is around 780px ... it's always possible that we are looking at different things ;)

Good luck!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yep, that turned out to be the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

.navbar .brand has

```
margin-left:-20px;
```

so the behavior seems normal to me.
Set it back to 0 via your mediaquerie

edit :  remove padding on body at :

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
body {
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
}
```

and margin at .navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom, .navbar-static-top :

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom, .navbar-static-top {
margin-right: -20px;
margin-left: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Tried it. Still doesn't eliminate the white right margin across the entire site. Thank you for your suggestion though!

Comment: it was meant to set back your link back on screen, not to avoid  you using your margin reset.

Comment: it's a padding on body and negative margin on navbar, see answer updated.